# How to chill and reheat three layer pork properly

Tags: pork

Usually, I put the three layer pork on the table and let it cool before putting it in the fridge to store for later cooking if I could not finish all of them in a meal. (Wonder if I am doing is correct?)

However, when I took them out to cook again, I notice that the there is a layer of oil (that looks like rubber). Should I remove this oil or should I wait until it reaches room temperature? Or should I simply just heat it up or how should I reheat them?

**Three Layer Pork**

[image]

Comment: To be clear, are you freezing this dish in the freezer, or chilling it in the fridge?

Comment: +1 Thanks Chris, I was just looking for the word chilling. Sorry for my poor Language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to say from the picture, but pork fat when cooled in a refrigerator does not have the texture of rubber. It is firm but stays deformed when you squish it. What does have the texture of rubber and could have come from the pork is gelatin. When you cool certain cuts of beef, pork, or other meats you break down the connective tissue and dissolve the gelatin in the cooking liquid or meat juices. If you cooked it, cut it, and then chilled the cut pieces they likely let out some of their juices and those juices then set (gelled) in the refrigerator due to the gelatin.

I would just heat it up, and the gelatinized juices will become liquid again.